# Обход запрета автозапуск iframe Chrome

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Я делаю веб страничку, которая ведет стрим с youtube, как мне сделать, чтобы при запуске страницы видео начинало идти со звуком? Если я запускаю со IFrame без параметра `mute=1`, то видео не запускается, если с ним, то все работает, но потом в коде, когда я использую `.unMute()` браузер ругается и останавливает видео, т.к. пользователь не взаимодействовал с ним.

Comment: Это неправильное поведение сайта, где без инициации пользователя запускается видео со звуком. Поэтому сделайте какой то функционал чтобы пользователь управлял звуком, а не скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Да. Это новое(уже 6 месяцев если память не изменяет)  обновление Google Chrome. И теперь Chrome очень сильно ругается на сайты с автовоспроизведением звука и не только.
Вот можете прочитать про это тут: [Блокировка рекламы Chrome](https://techno.nv.ua/it-industry/novaja-versija-brauzera-google-chrome-budet-blokirovat-avtovosproizvedenie-video-so-zvukom-2459470.html)

Comment: Да, я читал, но говорят, что это можно обойти

Comment: Можно громкость ставить на минимальные значения 0,005. Но этот костыль обещали пофиксить

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [новым стандартам](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) принятым в Апреле 2018, и окончательно вступившим в силу в Декабре 2018:

1. Воспроизведение "Без звука" разрешено всегда
2. Автовоспроизведение "Со звуком" разрешено если:

   - Юзер инициировал воспроизведение сам, с одного домена (клик, тап, др.).
   - На десктопных устройствах видео является доверенным по [Media Engagement Index](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei) и/или воспроизводилось ранее этим же пользователем.
   - На мобильных устройствах данный ресурс был добавлен на главный экран (см. [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/))
3. Разрешение на автовоспроизведение делегировано с верхних фреймов.

**Как обойти?**

По прежнему работает "хак" с  установкой минимального и неслышимого уровня громкости: *0,005*, и инициацией видео по любому действию пользователя, а потом уже накрутки громкости как потребуется. Но это также обещали пофиксить, поэтому это тоже является Bad Practice.

**Совет**

Не стройте велосипед из хаков и следуйте конвенциям, иначе Ваши работы никогда не будут работать нормально.